# Translating SQL code into Razor format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, razor

I am trying to translate some old C# code to emply the WebMatrix way of accessing Databases but I am struggling. Can someone please help me out ?

```
    private static string connectionString = "Data Source=ASHIT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=amit;Integrated Security=True";

    public static List<Item> method(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {

        List<Item> events = new List<Item>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT event_id, description, title, event_start, event_end FROM event where event_start>=@start AND event_end<=@end", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);

        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //perform functions
            }
        }
        return events;
    }
```

So far, I have this much, and I am not able to complete past the "Using" line - where should I go from here?

```
public static List<Item> method(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {

        List<Item> events = new List<Item>();
        var db = Database.Open("plan");
        var result = db.Query("SELECT event_id, description, title, event_start, event_end FROM event where event_start>= "+ start + " AND event_end<= "+ @end);
    //not sure what to do from here
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //perform functions
            }
        }
        return events;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used WebMatrix's database helpers, but based on the documentation you should be able to do something like:

```
foreach(var record in result)
{
    // Perform functions
}
```

---

Looking at the docs again, it looks like `db.Query` is going to return an `IEnumerable<Object>` so the code above won't work unless you change it to (C#4 only):

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result = db.Query("SELECT event_id, description, title, event_start, event_end FROM event where event_start>= "+ start + " AND event_end<= "+ @end);
```

This may not be necessary based on the example [here](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2011/01/24/strongly-typed-data-access-with-webmatrix-data/).